# Why use log-probability estimates in GaussianNB [scikit-learn]?

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm currently using scikit-learn's [GaussianNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) package.

I've noticed that I can choose to return results for the classification several different ways. One way to return a classification is using the predict_log_proba method.

Why would I choose to use predict_log_proba versus predict_proba versus predict?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- **predict** just gives you the class for every example
- **predict_proba** gives you the probability for every class, and **predict** is just taking the class which maximal probability
- **predict_log_proba** gives you the logarithm of the probabilities, this is often handier as probabilities can become very, very small

Answer (score 9):

When computing with probabilities, it's quite common to do so in log-space instead of in linear space because probabilities often need to be multiplied, causing them to become very small and subject to rounding errors. Also, some quantities like [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) are either defined or easily computed in terms of log-probabilities (note that log(P/Q) = log(P) - log(Q)).

Finally, Naive Bayes classifiers typically work in logspace themselves for reasons of stability and speed, so first computing `exp(logP)` only to get `logP` back later is wasteful.

Comment: If all you care about is the relative probabilities between two elements, e.g. for sorting, you can also save time by never calculating `exp` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the problem first,
posterior for vector's {w1, w2, w3, w4_ _ _ _ _ _ w_d}

P(y=1|w1,w2,w3,_ _ *,w_d) = P(y=1)*P(w1|y=1)*P(w2|y=1)*P(w2|y=1)** _ _ _  *P(w_d|y=1)

let assume the random probability of each LIKELIHOOD,

P(y=1|w1,w2,w3,_ _ *,w_d) = 0.6 * 0.2 * 0.23 * 0.04 * 0.001 * 0.45 * 0.012* _ SO ON

nowhere is a problematic situation while multiplication the LIKELIHOOD,

note:- In python, a float is **rounded** to some number of significant figures. it means you cannot gate correct results when you have numbers of *likelihoods*.

for solving this critical problem we use log probability.
the nice property of log is it's a **monotonic function** and it **converts multiplication to addition** and gives a fast and accurate result compared to a simple multiplication.

log(P(y=1|w1,w2,w3,_ _ *,w_d)) = log(P(y=1)*P(w1|y=1)*P(w2|y=1)*P(w2|y=1)** _ _ _  *P(w_d|y=1))

Now it's good